# jenkinsでrspecのテストを回した時に、js_errors: falseを指定しているにもかかわらず、jsのエラーが出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, jenkins, poltergeist

railsのフィーチャースペックをpoltergeistを用いてjenkins上で回しているのですが、

> エラーメッセージ
>
> One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details)....
>
> スタックトレース
>
> One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).
>
> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $td
>   ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $td
>       at h ttp://127.0.0.1:38079/assets/admin/application.js:14065
>   [object Object]
>   [object Object]
>       at h ttp://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=HOGE:51
>       at h ttp://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=HOGE:59 (Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError)
>   Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
>   One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).
>
> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $td
>   ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $td
>       at h ttp://127.0.0.1:38079/assets/admin/application.js:14065
>   [object Object]
>   [object Object]
>       at h ttp://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=HOGE:51
>       at h ttp://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=HOGE:59
>        ./spec/features/admin/hoge_spec.rb:237:in `block (4 levels) in '

のように、javascriptのエラーが出て、落ちてしまいます(hoge_specの名前およびurlのidを変更しています。また、urlを含めるなと言われたので、httpをh ttpとしています)。上の情報は一例で、エラーが起きる場所は毎回やるたびに変わっています。
spec_helper.rbの内容は以下です。

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'simplecov'
require 'simplecov-rcov'
SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::RcovFormatter
SimpleCov.start do
  add_filter '/vendor/'
end

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = !true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end

  config.before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.before :all do
    FactoryGirl.reload
  end

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include Login
  config.include NewWindow

  config.before do
    if page.driver.try :headers
      page.driver.headers = { 'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36' }
    end
  end

  config.after do |example|
    example = example.example
    if example.metadata[:type] == :feature and Capybara.javascript_driver == :poltergeist and example.exception.present?
      page.save_screenshot "spec/screenshot/#{example.full_description}.png"
    end
  end
end

Capybara.default_wait_time = ENV['WAIT_TIME'] || 3

require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
# require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Phantomjs.path

# Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome
# Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_firefox
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  driver = Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, js_errors: false, timeout: 10000, phantomjs: Phantomjs.path, phantomjs_options: ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes','--ssl-protocol=any'])
  driver.headers = { 'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36' }
  driver
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_firefox do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36'
  profile["general.useragent.override"] = ua
  opts = { browser: :firefox, profile: profile }
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, opts)
end
```

以上のように、js_errors: falseをつけているにもかかわらず、javascriptのエラーが起こったらテストが落ちます。
javascriptのエラーを治そうにも、tagmanager由来のエラーもあるようで、難しいかなと思いっています。
ローカル環境で同一のテストを回したところjavascriptのエラーでテストが落ちなかったので、jenkins環境によるのかなと思っています。
どうすればjavascriptのエラーを無視して、rspecのテストを落ちないようにできるでしょうか。

環境:
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
ruby 2.1.5p273
Rails 4.0.5
Jenkins ver. 1.552
phantomjs 1.9.2
poltergeist (1.6.0)

Comment: 実際に `js_errors` が有効になっているか知りたいのですが、`page.driver.browser.js_errors = false` をテストケースの中に書くと、どうなりますか？

Comment: spec_helper.rbの`config.before`の中に、featureスペックで`page.driver.browser.respond_to?(:js_error=)`がtrueの時だけ`page.driver.browser.js_errors = false`を実行するようにするとjavascriptのエラーでテストが落ちることがなくなりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

根本的な対策にはなりませんが、テスト実行中のみ読み込まない、というアプローチがあります。

```
<%= javascript_include_tag('//example.com/foo_bar.js') unless Rails.env.test? %>
```

自分が書いたJSのコードなら警告やエラーを解消すべきですが、GoogleやFacebook等、外部のスクリプトは自分では制御しがたいものが多いので、何度か試行錯誤してムリだったら諦める、というのも一つの手です。（実際過去にそうしたプロジェクトもあります）

ただし、当然ですがエラーの原因となっているJSがテストの実行に必要不可欠なものであれば、このアプローチは使えません。